# How can I continuously follow the cursor of a person in Google Docs?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

**Background:**

I can click on the avatar of a user to see his current cursor position in Google Docs or Google Sheets.

However, I need to repeatedly click on the avatar if I want to follow the user continuously.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Google Docs Avatar]

**Question:**

Is there any possibility to continuously follow the cursor of a user without having to repeatedly click on his avatar?

Comment: I made a try. When a user is in the same sheet, you may see his cursor mowing. But when a user goes to another sheet or moving down the page, you are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible at this time. It's worth to say that there a couple of related features:

- File > Revision History
- File > See new changes

For further details see [See the history of changes made to a file](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190843?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

You could open up the browser console and do this:

```
const name = "Anonymous Moose"
const refreshSeconds = 5
const noteTaker = $$(`#docs-presence img[alt="${name}"]`)[0]
setInterval(() => noteTaker.click(), refreshSeconds*1000)
```

I use this when I want to project meeting minutes on a wall, from a laptop that I'm not using. Then the projected tab keeps following my cursor (assuming I'm visible as "Anonymous Moose" or whatever, after joining).

(Note: It seems that sometimes GDocs gets suspicious and says "there's an issue" and forces a restart. I'm not sure how long this can run without raising concern with Google's automation that something is being puppetted, or used maliciously.)